# Cast vs Serialize/Deserialize C#

Tags: c#, serialization, casting, deserialization

### Scenario

I have a `virtual` method in a base class, which takes an `object` as a parameter.

I override this in derived classes - more specifically, view models - in order to work with the different objects from there, also:

```
public override void SomeMethod(object parameter)
{
    // ...

    base.SomeMethod(parameter);
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to clarify - I am unable to change the `SomeMethod` signature in the base class - unfortunately, I'm stuck with `object` as the type :(

Let's say that each derived class will expect a different type to the next, but I know about what type each class needs to use in order to pass it and consume it.

In particular, I will ask about `Dictionary<string, string>`; but I would be interested to see if this applies to other types.

---

### Imagine this...

So, let's say I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` I want to pass to `SomeMethod()`:

Here's the dictionary:

```
// create the dictionary
var myItem = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["Key1"] = "Value1",
    ["Key2"] = "Value2"
    // ...
};
```

---

### What I have so far...

#### Possibilities...

There are 2 possible ways that I can think of in order to pass `myItem` to the `SomeMethod()`:

```
// Pass the myItem directly as an object

SomeMethod(myItem);
```

or

```
// Serialize the myItem to a string, and then pass that as an object
// I'm using JsonConvert in this case

object parameter = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myItem);
SomeMethod(parameter);
```

#### Consuming the item

Then, I can use 2 possible ways to consume the item I've just passed to `SomeMethod()`, depending on which method I've used above respectively:

```
public override void SomeMethod(object parameter)
{
    // Cast the parameter back to a dictionary
    Dictionary<string, string> unboxedItem = parameter as Dictionary<string, string>;

    // consume away...
}
```

or

```
public override void SomeMethod(object parameter)
{
    // Deserialize the parameter from a string
    Dictionary<string, string> deserializedItem =
                    JsonConvert
                    .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(parameter as string);

    // consume away...
}
```

---

### Help?

Which of these 2 methods will be less resource-intensive?

<strike>I have heard that boxing and unboxing can be end up being slow (in large-scale circumstances).</strike>

Yes, I understand that I'm actually boxing the serialized `string` in the second method - does it matter from/to which type I'm boxing/unboxing in terms of resources?

Will casting to/from an object have an impact on performance? Or, will the de/serialization be the real performance-hit?

**UPDATE:** So, it seems I've been a bit of a silly sausage and misunderstood about the boxing/unboxing stuff - so I've updated the question to reflect this

Many thanks in advance for your comments, suggestions and help :)

Comment: That has nothing to do with unboxing.  Casts are cheap; parsing is _very expensive_.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  If you want to optimize on this level, you first need to understand what boxing really is and why it's slow.

Comment: Boxing??  No.  Use the *dynamic* keyword if the argument type is dynamic.

Comment: Actually, you should use generics instead, and stop using `object` entirely.

Comment: For the sake of argument, I'm unable to change the base class' `SomeMethod` and parameter types. I'll update the question just to clarify this.

Comment: You are actually not doing unboxing in that example, only a cast. Unboxing is passing a reference type to a value type. In your case both are reference types. So let me see if I understand, you want to have a common interface to pass around a message to different members of a chain?

Comment: Thanks, @SLaks for your suggestion and comments :) very helpful. Unfortunately, I'm unable to change the base class' `SomeMethod` signature (sucks, I know) - otherwise generics would be the first place I'd go :)

Comment: Thanks @Cat_Clan - very good explanation. That's right - I need to pass this around using the base's `SomeMethod`. I've obviously changed some names and stuff for brevity - but, in short - the base class is implementing `INavigationAware` and the required type in the signature is `object` (hence why I can't change it) - it's the `OnNavigatedTo`/`OnNavigatedFrom` events. Hope this helps make it a little clearer :)

Comment: Is that the case, casting is your best option. Is not that expensive, just make sure to check for null after using as, to ensure casting was correct.

Comment: Updated the question, as I've been a bit of a numpty and misunderstood the concept of boxing/unboxing - whoops!

Comment: @Cat_Clan -- that's good to know, thank you. Yes - I'm checking for null, hence the `as` safe-cast to avoid exceptions being thrown :)

Comment: On a second thought, there is one other option. To have a new base class that works as an adapter with a new Generic interface, and this new base class would make the castings. But might be an overkill if you are only coding this in a few places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, boxing is not what's happening here. Boxing refers to the operation of preparing *value types* to be put on the heap as reference types. If your dictionary was a value type, it would indeed need to be boxed and unboxed.

Alas, a dictionary is a reference type. And that means there will be no boxing. The reference will be passed as is to your method. What your method will have to do is a *downcast* to a dictionary. While this requires the RTTI (run time type information) of your object to be evaluated, the performance impact will usually not be noticed (except in extreme cases).

Your serialization/deserialization solution however is much more expensive. You will have to allocate space for a string on the heap, you have to serialize, deserialize and the string will eventually need to be garbage collected. You can expect that to be far more expensive than a simple downcast.

**UPDATE:**

Just to make that clear, you can still expect boxing to be cheaper than serialization. So even for value types there is no reason choose serialization. Especially since there is a pretty high chance you will have *at least* one boxing operation in the whole serialization round trip.

Comment: Thanks for this information - very useful to know. I think it might be clear that I've misunderstood how boxing/unboxing works *(doh! - coffee time...)*. I'll make sure I'm not de/serializing unnecessarily in future. Thank you again :)